# How to make contingency table for two satellite images in R language

Tags: qgis, r

I am working on forest change detection in an area. I have taken two satellite images 2001 and 2016 to depict the forest change. I have taken four classes while classifying the images i.e., forest, non-forest, snow and water bodies.

I want to know, how we can make contingency table of both the  two satellite images. The contingency table must show the change of pixel like how many pixels of class forest were present in 2001 and how many of those pixels transferred in 2016 in another class.

Comment: You should provide some code for a good answer, but a workaround could be `table(raster::values(scene_2001),raster::values(scene_2016))`

Comment: Could you please tell me more, if possible with an example.

Comment: @sourabsingh *you* should give an example - you shouldn't expect people answering questions here to do all the work of preparing data etc. You should try and give sample code that creates test datasets that we can use to help answer you. Edit your question to help us help you.

Comment: # Adding images #
classified <- raster("E:/3rd_semester_project_work/classified_GEE/project/mask2000/mask2000.tif")
classified1 <- raster("E:/3rd_semester_project_work/classified_GEE/project/mask2016/mask2016.tif")
# Comparing the images to generate contingency table #
table(raster::values("E:/3rd_semester_project_work/classified_GEE/project/mask2000/mask2000.tif"),raster::values("E:/3rd_semester_project_work/classified_GEE/project/mask2016/mask2016.tif")) BUT ITS NOT WORKING , NEED SOME HELP

Comment: Did you read function documentation? Why are you using a path inside `values()`. Check `help(values)`

Answer (score 2):

The [crosstab](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/crosstab) function in the raster package will make this for you, results are returned as pixel counts which can then be converted to area.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but could you please tell me more. If possible with an example.

Comment: From the crosstab documentation
#making example rasters

r <- raster(nc=5, nr=5)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 2
s <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)) * 3)
crosstab(r,s)